# Additional shipping cost for each additional item in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create a function for woocommerce with which when a visitor adds more than one product in their cart, $2 is added in addition every product quantity to the shipping cost for every product.

For example one product, shipping cost is applicable. For additional product or more than 1 quantity it adds $2 to the shipping cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be do through settings in your "flat rate" shipping method cost field.

- If your flat rate initial cost is $10
- If you want to add $2 for each additional item *(or quantity)*

You will be able to set the following in the "flat rate" shipping method cost field:

```
8.00+(2.00*[qty])
```

[image]

Comment: This is applying on even a single quantity. If I have only 1 quantity then it should not apply on that but more than 1 quantity of that product or any product.

Comment: @MarkAnderson I know but this is necessary: for the first item: (8 + (2 * 1) make 10) where 10 is the initial cost | Then 2 for each additional item…

Comment: Your solution is good and I feel that I should get along with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

8.00+(2.00*([qty]-1))
Will subtract the original item and not add the addon uuntil there are more than one items.